# A sequence to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the infinite sequence have a possible closed form? Minus sign is not a mistake, it's in the right place.

$$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\cdots}}}}}$$

The sequence of signs has period $4$ $(+,+,-,+)$

Comment: Does the minus ever repeat?  i.e. is there one inside the 6th radical (the one right now is inside the 3rd radical)

Comment: With the sequence of signs having period 4, you have $x = \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+x}}}}$. If you rewrite that eliminating the square roots, you get an equation of degree $2^4 = 16$. I don't expect that to be easily solved.

Comment: @DanielFischer Lazy people like me solve it [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dsqrt%285%2Bsqrt%285%2B+sqrt%285-sqrt%285%2Bx%29%29%29+%29).

Comment: @julien Neat. Didn't expect it to have such a simple closed form.

Comment: @julien this seems to be the answer I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @DanielFisher you should draw the function
$$
  f(x) = \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+x}}}}
$$
and compare with the function $x$, as [here](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=546&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=sqr%285%20%2bsqrt%285%20%2bsqrt%285-sqrt%285%2b%20x%29%29%29%29,x&btnG=). It is apparent the the sequence converges and the solution is approximately 2.74

Comment: And if you read all the comments, you'll see the WA manages to find the closed form.

Comment: Well, more exactly: WA manages to give some closed form that we'd like to believe it is the correct one...Only in the last 2 - 3 weeks or so there were found at least two bugs related to some questions in WA, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right to be careful. Here is a [double-check](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285-%28%28x%5E2-5%29%5E2-5%29%5E2%29%5E2-x+%3B+++++x%3D1%2F2+%282%2Bsqrt%285%29%2Bsqrt%2815-6+sqrt%285%29%29%29). Still with WA, though... But together with the approximation 2.74, this seems correct.